# "an integer is required" when open()'ing a file as utf-8?

Tags: python, utf-8

I have a file I'm trying to open up in python with the following line:

```
f = open("C:/data/lastfm-dataset-360k/test_data.tsv", "r", "utf-8")
```

Calling this gives me the error

> TypeError: an integer is required

I deleted all other code besides that one line and am still getting the error.  What have I done wrong and how can I open this correctly?

Comment: What does the traceback say? Is the last line the `f = open(...)` line, or inside the python core libraries?

Comment: which version of Python? 3.x? or 2.x?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the documentation for [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open):

> **`open(name[, mode[, buffering]])`**
>
> [...]
>
> The optional buffering argument specifies the file’s desired buffer
>   size: 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line buffered, any other positive
>   value means use a buffer of (approximately) that size. A negative
>   buffering means to use the system default, which is usually line
>   buffered for tty devices and fully buffered for other files. If
>   omitted, the system default is used.

You appear to be trying to pass `open()` a string describing the file encoding as the third argument instead. Don't do that.

Comment: Shoot.  You're right.  I was meaning to use codecs.open.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You are using the wrong open.

```
>>> help(open)
Help on built-in function open in module __builtin__:

open(...)
    open(name[, mode[, buffering]]) -> file object

    Open a file using the file() type, returns a file object.  This is the
    preferred way to open a file.  See file.__doc__ for further information.
```

As you can see it expects the buffering parameter which is a integer.

What you probably want is [codecs.open](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open):

```
open(filename, mode='rb', encoding=None, errors='strict', buffering=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

From the help docs:

```
open(...)
    open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None,
         errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True) -> file object
```

you need `encoding='utf-8'`; python thinks you are passing in an argument for buffering.

Answer (score 2):

This resolved my issue, ie providing an encoding(utf-8) while opening the file

```
    with open('tomorrow.txt', mode='w', encoding='UTF-8', errors='strict', buffering=1) as file:
file.write(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter to [`open`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) is the size of the buffer, not the encoding of the file.

File streams are more or less encoding-agnostic (with the exception of newline translation on files not open in binary mode), you should handle encoding elsewhere (e.g. when you get the data with a `read()` call, you can interpret it as `utf-8` using its `decode` method).